# Issues creating simple react-native module for mobile and web

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-web

I have a question in regards to creating a simple react module that can be used by both mobile and react native web.

I defined the simple Component in react native module - see index.js below. 
Now for react native web, the index.js needs to be translated into ES5 (e.g. /node_modules/.bin/babel src --out-file index.js). However, for mobile it does not need to be translated.

My question is how I can make this Component available for both web and as part of a react module? (since there's only one main property in the package.json).

**index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

class DummyComponent extends Component {

    render () {
        return (
            <Text>hello World</Text>
        )
    }

}

export default DummyComponent;
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "react-test-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test module",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/babel src --out-file index.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "author": "The man",
  "license": "MIT",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react-native": "^0.61.5",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.7.7",
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.4",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-native": "^0.61.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.7.4",
    "react-native": "^0.61.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by making it available for web? If you just want react-native-web there should be no transpilation needed and you can just reference your normal index.js as main entrypoint in the package.json

Comment: try using create-react-app for web.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want two different versions what you can do it to use platform specific extensions for index file.

You can create three files for `index.js` so one will be simply `index.js` and you can use that for web version which you can translate and you can create two different files

`index.ios.js` and `index.android.js` that will be used for mobile and these can be exactly as you have your file now.

These are two files that will be picked automatically by the platform in which you are running.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web), no need to use any other translation.

You can refer very nice documentation [here](http://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/?path=/docs/overview-getting-started--page)

If you want to use **Create React App**

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm install react-native-web
npm start
```

If stand-alone app then follow steps [here](http://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/?path=/docs/overview-getting-started--page)

Answer (score 0):

If you want this component to work on both a React web app and React Native, I think [ReactXP](https://github.com/microsoft/reactxp) should be what you want

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'reactxp';

class DummyComponent extends RX.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <RX.Text>Hello World</RX.Text>
        )
    }

}

export default DummyComponent;
```